# Bulk change Manager name in distribution list

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2007

How do i change in bulk manager name for specipic distribution list

Comment: It looks like you're getting a few powershell answers. I strongly suggest that you have a look into PowerShell as it's an incredibly useful tool for dealing with exchange and Active Directory. Also, if you find an answer useful, you should give it an upvote and if it answers your question, give it the tick-mark so that the person who answered can get some hard-earned reputation for their effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell will help you out here.
*Get-ADGroupMember* will get you the contents of your list, and *Set-ADUser* will modify the parameters of each user.

You're looking for something like

```
Get-AdGroupMember -Identity "DL Name" | Set-ADUser -Manager "New Manager" -WhatIf
```

That will show you what users it's making the change to, and confirm that it can find the new manager name you gave it. When you're satisfied, remove the -WhatIf to actually make the changes.

Comment: I had tried said query but its does not recognized command (Get-Addgroupmember)

Comment: I'll recommend finding a good resource on PowerShell - it's amazingly powerful (and the Exchange Management Console is really just a wrapper around PowerShell, so it's useful to know what's going on behind the scenes). Anyhow, make sure you're typing it in correctly (there's only one 'd' in AD). You may not also have the AD module imported. Make sure you're running PS as an administrator, and run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` before you try the command.

Comment: Thx, after running import module it has identify but got another issue i will be appriciate if can assist me for this too.. Set-ADUSer : A referral was returned from the server

Comment: Hmm. This is getting a little bit involved - you have a nontrivial AD setup there, and the command is not talking to the right Domain Controller. I'm not comfortable expanding on this without knowing more about your environment - is there someone else on your team you can talk to for help making this work?

Comment: some how i have been resolved even this issue unfortunatly encounter with new issue again hope you can assist for this too.   trying to change manager account reside in different domain and DL is different domain, error comes up with (Identity info provided in the extended attribute 'Manager' could not be resolved. Reason cannot find an object with identity

Comment: That just means it can't find the manager you're looking for. Try a different way of naming the manager. If you can type `Get-AdUser -Identity ManagerName` and have it return the individual you want, that'll be what you need to give the initial command.

Comment: Let me provide you commplete command (Get-AdGroupMember -Identity "DL Name" | Set-ADUser -Manager "Name of manager") issue is that DL is in different domain1 and user account in different Domain2, error appear as mention earlier comments

Comment: In that case you'll need to qualify the user names - DOMAIN1\DL Name and DOMAIN2\Manager Name.